# Cómo leer una variable que es entregada como texto

Tags: javascript

Estoy obteniendo una variable con todo y su contenido y tal variable es insertada como cadena de texto en un div pero no sé cómo leerla después. intenté hacerlo con *JSON.parse* pero no funciona ya que no lo reconoce como *JSON*.

```js
let s = document.querySelector(".variable_con_contenido");

document.write(JSON.parse(s.innerText).info);
```

```html
<div class="variable_con_contenido">let info = "DD51ssal5s11..."</div>
```

Comment: document.querySelector(".variable_con_contenido").innerText  ????

Comment: Hola, una nota al margen de la solución de Yussef, si no me equivoco, estas intentando declarar una variable dentro del div... **let info = "DD51ssal5s11..."**, eso no funciona, lo tomará todo como un texto, incluidas las comillas, y eso es lo que imprimirá, **`<div class="variable_con_contenido"> DD51ssal5s11 </div>`** es probablemente lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es aclarar que un [JSON](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) es un texto (string) que tiene una estructura definida y normada, NO es cualquier texto y NO es código javascript, por tanto tu `JSON.parse` no funcionará nunca

Para evaluar texto como código javascript existen artes oscuras como [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) que en tu caso habría funcionado si usaras `var` en vez de `let`, o otras menos polémicas como pero igualmente peligrosas como`new Function(texto)`

No obstante, tal y como planteas el problema, la solución que a mi parecer es más simple, es crear un elemento `script` añadirle el texto. Algo así:

```js
let contenido = document.querySelector(".variable_con_contenido").innerText;
let script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerText=contenido;
document.body.appendChild(script);

console.log(info);
```

```html
<div class="variable_con_contenido">let info = "DD51ssal5s11..."</div>
```

Otra alternatica sería simplemnte hacer un `split("=")` al texto y quedarte con la parte derecha

```js
let contenido = document.querySelector(".variable_con_contenido").innerText;
let asignacion = contenido.split("=")[1].trim();

console.log(asignacion);
```

```html
<div class="variable_con_contenido">let info = "DD51ssal5s11..."</div>
```